# Implementing version to C program

Tags: c, makefile, macros, version

I have a code that compiles to either debug version, user input version, and file input version. Each of them is built from the same source code where using #ifdef macros the Makefile creates the version of choice. Is it possible to implement a version tracker, so that I can check from the terminal which is the version of the binary? For example, something like

```
binary --version
```

That would return 0 for debug, 1 for user input, 2 for file input.

Alternative options are welcome.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Where do you have difficulties ?

Comment: That's not really a "version" you want to print, but a build-type or -variant. And yes it is possible. Exactly how depend on how you set the build-type and pass it to the compiler and the source.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Could you please give some extra details how setting the build-type can be done?

Comment: You have a makefile that does different things depending on some flags or variables? How does that happen? Does the makefile pass some preprocessor macro to the compiler that tells which kind of build it's making? Then do you know how to use the preprocessor `#if` or `#ifdef` directives? Then you already have the basics, all you then need is to parse the arguments. But I *can't* give more details, because *you* are the one who have the details, not me.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg In the makefile I have the variable VERSION. Its value is passed from the command line when calling make: make VERSION="-DUSERINPUT". In the source code I have portions of the code surrounded by #ifdef USERINPUT ... #endif

Comment: Then you already seem to have everything you need to return or print the build type. What is it you have trouble with? Parsing the arguments? Something else? Please elaborate! Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, if I compiled the binary last week and I no longer remember which one it was, how can I check what I compiled without recompiling again? That is the idea of my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I *still* say you have everything you need. *And* much of the knowledge to use it. In your program you check if the user gave the special argument to check your "version". Then you use conditional compilation using the preprocessor (the `#ifdef`/`#endif` chain) to select what to print (or return).